# Logging specific SQL statement types

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Is there a way to log only specific types of SQL statements in SQLAlchemy? E.g. I need to log `INSERT` statements only.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about SQLAlchemy, but there is a thing called a trigger in SQL. It's like a procedure but it's table-specific and executes only when a certain is performed on the table. More on triggers [here](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/an-introduction-to-triggers-part-i) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_trigger).